# Parity syncing pauses for long periods

Tags: windows, ethereum, parity-io

I've been having issues with my parity instance freezing up while syncing. Given enough time it'll generally pick up again but sometimes it will stay where it is for hours. Restarting the instance temporarily solves the problem and it will immediately start syncing like normal.

For example, it might sync to the latest block at 15:00:00 and then not pick up anything until 15:30:00 (or a few hours later) and then start syncing until it catches back up to the top.

Peers are generally 20+ and absolutely nothing new will show up in the console until parity decides to resume (or I restart)

Running off of a windows server instance. Off of an HDD (Not ideal I know but except for these pauses it has been sufficient and the fact that restarting parity fixes the issue makes me believe it is unrelated to the hard drive performance)

Running parity 1.10.8 with the cmd:

```
parity.exe --jsonrpc-apis all --cache-size 1024 --db-compaction hdd --tracing off --pruning fast
```

I have a large number of wallets that I query regularly with the RPC APIs to check for changes.

Did anyone encounter anything like this?

Answer (score 1):

That is a known bug and fixed a while ago, if you keep experiencing this, please ugprade to the latest Parity Ethereum 2.x releases!

https://github.com/paritytech/parity-ethereum/releases/latest

---

*Note: I work for Parity Technologies.*